# async:false deprecated, What's the simple way forward?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

Browsers warn according to the [whatwg](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) specification of Synchronous XMLHttpRequest. From the warning, the reason for deprecation is clear *"User experience"*

*My problem is :*

1. **What is a simple replacement to this?** Could they not update JS such
   that it does not stop every other JS code in the browser but just
   the one in the running thread?

*This is pertinent because there are several times when we need to use `async:false`. Which does not require any "complex" methods like Data Binding, Deffering or even placing code in the `.done()` or `.fail()` methods. (when using Jquery.)*

2. Is the developer not suppose to worry about "user experience" for
   his own users more than these standards impose for?

Warning thrown by Firefox:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help
>   http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Code Snippet (**JQuery**) Example to generate warning :

```js
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "GET",
  data: {},
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
      //Do something
  },

  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    //Throw error message

  }
});

//Wait for $.ajax to finish execution the continue ...
```

Comment: Just remove the `async: false`. You're already using the callbacks that you should be. The only reason to use sync requests is in the `onbeforeunload` event. All other cases, including those you listed, should be done in an async manner. To answer your questions, 1) They already have, it's asynchronous requests. 2) I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I know removing that takes away the warning... But am asking this because I don't want the action that is "waited" for to be executed inside the callback.

Comment: So don't include the callback. You seem confused about the purpose of async code.

Comment: Alright maybe I haven't expressed my concerns right. About point two I just thought, it should not be deprecated so developers can choose to use it or not if it does not affect their user's experience.

Comment: But that's the problem - it *does affect the user's experience*. It hangs the browser window while the request is in progress. If the response doesn't come back quickly then the user often believes the browser has crashed and will close the frozen tab, or even force quit the browser itself. This is why sync requests have been deprecated and async should always be used instead.

Comment: It is not hard to learn to code properly using asynchronous methods

Comment: The only places it should be used are those mentioned by @RoryMcCrossan and in WebWorkers (if needed) as those won't hang the main thread which **does** affect the users experience.

Comment: Thanks, that's clear now. But is there not a walk-around for the browser implementations?

Comment: No there isn't and you should get out of that way of thinking completely. The whole practice has been avoided for many many years

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan and charlietfl. Thanks for the explanations. I guess I have to force my lazy ass to do the right stuff.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do (in the callback)? / Why can't it be async? In my mind an AJAX call is always async... (it's in the name).

Comment: While there is no excuse for user generated sites to have async AJAX, for internal apps, synchronous AJAX requests are quite useful, particularly if you're trying to organize your code in a way that doesn't have multiple nested AJAX  calls.

Answer (score 0):

The sync way can be used to dynamically load external .js files. Having to load 3 or 4 external modules throws you in the callback hell if you use imbricated callbacks. Instead, you can do it as usual when loading your html page, and then we do not care about the "User Experience" ? Would using a module loader be of any help ?

Answer (score 0):

ok i presuming that you need this to load  this file or data to use when the user click something  for example . so you can do this way ;

```js
 var lol = {};
 var dataOutSide = null;
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=NNKOjkoul8n1CH18TWA9gwngW1s1SmjESPjNoUFo');
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log(xhr.response); // use this to build if you need show this data when the page is loaded
      dataOutSide = xhr.response; // use this to  if you need show this data anytime after the page is loaded

    } else {
      console.error('big fail! :(');
    }
  }
};
xhr.send(); // and then you put you listeners like clicks inside  $(document).ready(function ....

  $(document).ready(function(){

$('#my-btn').click(function (event){ 
console.log(dataOutSide); // all stuff 
$('body > div').append('<img src="'+dataOutSide.url+'" />') }); // when i click my btn show me the image ;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
 <title></title>

</head>
<body>
       <div>
      <button id="my-btn">show me ! </button>
        </div>
</body>
```